# How to design the index to perform viewed by and viewed by me information

Tags: elasticsearch

```
UserA views UserB
UserA views UserC
UserD views UserA

Who Viewed You queries:-
Who Viewed You should show UserD for UserA
Who Viewed You should show UserA for UserB
Who Viewed You should show UserA for UserC

Viewed By Me queries:-
Viewed By Me should show UserA for UserD
```

How should we model the `users` index, to fetch the above information

```
users index contains first_name, last_name, gender, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just save a array in a visitors fields (or visited depending of the lower cardinality)

I guess that the docs can be huge so to optimize (and avoid a large number of updates), I would have a "visits_logs" indices with just logs and a LCM with a short delete phase. (one index a day and keeping one week of data before deletion)

```
{"visitor": "userA", "visited": "userB", "@timestamp": 12345678990}
```

Then at night, use a transformation of a manual aggregation to populate an aggregation index per period:

```
PUT visits/_doc
{
  "visitor": "UserA",
  "@timestamp": "today",
  "visited": {
      "users": ["UserB", "UserC", "UserD"],
      "quantity": 3
}
```

Details really depends on your real use case and volume of your data.
But I think it's a robust solution.

UPDATE:
The queries would be:

If you want to know all users visited by UserA

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "visitor": "UserA"
    }
  }
}
```

Response will looks like this and you just have to merge visited arrays

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.4700036,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5k-z3XQBDjdqjSSDl_K5",
        "_score" : 0.4700036,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "today",
          "visited" : {
            "users" : [
              "UserB",
              "UserC",
              "UserD"
            ],
            "quantity" : 3
          },
          "visitor" : "UserA"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Ksaz3XQBk-8NpR_boPe2",
        "_score" : 0.4700036,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "today",
          "visited" : {
            "users" : [
              "UserB",
              "UserC",
              "UserD"
            ],
            "quantity" : 3
          },
          "visitor" : "UserA"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you want to get "who visit userB"

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "visited.users": "UserB"
    }
  },
  "_source": ["@timestamp", "visitor"]
}
```

And the answers are then visitors.

You can have a more qualified result with aggregations

```
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "visited.users": "UserB"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "visitors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "visitor.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With a result like

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "visitors" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "UserA",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and for visited

```
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "visitor": "UserA"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "visits": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "visited.users.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with a result like:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "visits" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "UserB",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "UserC",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "UserD",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The queries needs to pull data in both ways, so If I say viewed by others for "UserB" how would this work